# Ssrs reports Windows 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I'm fairly new to SQL and I have been issued my first report to build. I have written an SQL query to give me a set of results that I would like to publish in a report.

I have unioned about 20 small queries all containing the correct amount of columns. One column is a misc column with about 15 different descriptions in (this is what I want to count).

I have uploaded my data set and now want to be able to choose a cell in my report to bring back a certain description.

At the minute I'm using

`=count(fields!misc.values)`

and it's giving me the whole count, about 200.

I would like to know if there is any kind of "where clause" (filter) which I can use to state which description results I want to bring back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use am expression to count the `misc.value` you need. It will work like a count using a where clause:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!misc.Value ="Some description",1,0))
```

Example:

[image]

For count the FSMethod with `MethodOne` as value I used this expression:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!FSMethod.Value ="MethodOne",1,0))
```

Note the expression sums by `1` if the `FSMethod.Value` is `MethodOne`.

For count the rows with FSMethod column with `MethodTwo` value.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!FSMethod.Value ="MethodTwo",1,0))
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Cheers I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Is it also possible to and a certain day to this as well?

Comment: @S.Parky what do you mean by _and a certain day_? You can use multiple conditions to count just add the logic operation with `AND` or `OR` operators just like a SQL `where` clause.

Comment: Hi , I have solved it with 'AND' sorry for dumb questions.